# How to configure multiple loggers in dll

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm new to log4net and I'm not quite sure how to set up my app.config correctly when there are multiple loggers in a dll.  Well I do but I'm wondering if there is an easier way when there are 10-20 different loggers.  It may also be that I just don't understand this.

Ok so let's say the dll uses the following loggers (it's actually about 20 different statements like this):

```cs
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(XmlConfiguration));
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ClassValidator));
```

Does this mean I need to do something like this in my app.config (I have omitted appenders for brevity)?

```xml
<logger name="XmlConfiguration" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileLog"/>
</logger>

<logger name="ClassValidator" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileLog"/>
</logger>
```

Can I configure it somehow such that each logger exposed by a particular dll or partial namespace (loggers in dll are under several different namespaces but have a common root namespace) all go to the same logging source (file, console etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You can set different login levels for different dlls by configuring multiple loggers :

Here is an example i have used successfully :

```
<!-- ALL|DEBUG|INFO|WARN|ERROR|FATAL|OFF -->
<root>
  <level value="Error"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
</root>

<logger name="NHibernate">
  <level value="ERROR" />
</logger>
```